# Set Autocomplete off of a textfield in Extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a textfiled which is auto-completing values in chrome, I want to remove it.

```
{
  xtype:'textfield',
  fieldLabel:'Name',
  name:'Name',
  reference: 'Name'
}
```

I have found below solution.

```
 afterrender:function(cmp){
       cmp.inputEl.set({
           autocomplete:'on'
      });
 }
```

But I need to do it using lookupReference.

```
var x= this.lookupReference('Name');
```

Comment: Expect hit and miss using autocomplete. There is a bug report to Chrome about their "ignoring" autocomplete settings to the point of breaking applications having implemented their own lookup/autocomplete. This battle has gone on for 3 or 4 years already

Answer (score 1):

To get your field via lookupReference() you have to set the reference config on the field.

```
    {
      xtype:'textfield',
      fieldLabel:'Name',
      name:'Name',
      reference: 'Name'
    }
```

Comment: its added there I missed it to write here as I have lots of properties, I forgot to write here . I am able to get the element using lookupReference but don't know to set autocomplete off with this. Modified component in question.

Comment: Why can't you just use your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno which toolkit you are using, but in Modern you can use:

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.field.Text.html#cfg-autoComplete

> autoComplete : Boolean BINDABLE `false to disable autocomplete on this
>   text field. Autocomplete is enabled by default on text fields, but
>   disabled on picker fields.
>
> Defaults to:
>
> true